# play form-helper not displaying inline

Tags: css, playframework

I'm new to the play framework and am trying to add a form to the top of my page with a simple username and password field and a submit button. I'm using the play form helper, but it won't allow me to have these fields side by side ,instead it always puts them on top of one another. I keep trying to change the CSS, but no luck.

Here's the relevant part of the HTML

> ```
>     <header id="top_header" class=rounded>
>         <div id="logo">
>             <h1>@message</h1>
>         </div>
>         <div id="login_pane">
>             <div id="login">
>             @helper.form(action=routes.Test.testFunction(), 'id->"login_form"){
>                 @helper.inputText(loginForm("username"), 'id->"username", '_label->"Username")
>                 @helper.inputPassword(loginForm("password"), 'id->"password", '_label->"Password")
>                 <input type="submit" value = "Enter" id="login_button">
>             }
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </header>
> ```

And the CSS

```
#top_header{
    background: yellow;
    height: 30px;
}

#logo{
    float: left;
    background: green;
    width: 200px;
}

#login_pane{
    float: right;
    background: blue;
    width: 500px;
}

#login{
    float: left;
    background: red;
}

#username, #password, #login_button{
    display: inline;
}
```

By the way, I just use the ugly background colours to see where things are positioned.
I've tried putting `display: inline` just about everywhere but it's having no effect. Has anybody any ideas on how to position the form elements side by side?

Comment: I guess you could put the username and password inputs in different divs and the position each one according to what you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the HTML source you can notice that the form-helper generating HTML like this (maybe similar not exactly identical) :

```html
<form action="/test/testFunction" method="GET" id="login_form">
    <dl class=" " id="username_field">
        <dt><label for="username">Username</label></dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" >
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class=" " id="password_field">
        <dt><label for="password">Password</label></dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" >
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <input type="submit" value = "Enter" id="login_button">
</form>
```

So, you can define your css based on `dl`, `dd`, or `dt` element to make it displayed side by side. This is simple but not best sample (I only tell you the basic) :

```css
#login_form dl {
   padding: 10px;
   float: left;
}
#login_form dd {
   margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Hope this useful for you friend.. :)

Comment: where can we find the generated HTML source in Play app ? I tried but can't find my App.